# Joint Sato-Tate equi-distribution formula for two Hilbert modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

Is there any Joint Sato-Tate equi-distribution formula for a pair Hilbert cusp forms ? 
Like for classical case we have Joint Sato-Tate equi-distribution formula for a pair cusp forms.

Comment: Have you looked at all the "potential modularity" stuff of the last few years?